# Answer deleted without reason?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/how-does-one-know-if-a-rental-car-takes-diesel-or-gasoline) was deleted without any reason given even though OP agreed it's certainly an option, so what's the reason for deletion?

Comment: Good question. I also wonder why, because the answer you gave was correct and your advice is probably the most sensible thing to do! Especially for drivers who are unsure about how a car functions.

Comment: Thank you. I find the right spirit lacking as in other SE's and trying to get a reasoning for wrong doing is like talking to a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Mayo came had a conversation which was deleted

@Karlson came repeated what @Mark Mayo said and left

@Ankur Banerjee came again repeated the same things as above two

> It was deleted by a moderator because it's a low quality answer. A standard guidance is:
>
> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

So, I update my question [with this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21722/11560) A one line answer which was **NOT** deleted. ( Please note I just happen to across this just by coincidence I am not searching for one liner answers I dont have time for that)

I am taking it as a serious offense that my answer given has been called *low quality* by all three mentioned above.

I stand by my answer that calling the car rental company is the best thing to do. If the car rental agency doesnot provide with emergency number then what will you do if you are in middle of nowhere and car breakdown and I repeat playing with fuel is **not a good idea**.

If the mod @mindcorrosive other members had an issue with the answer then suitable approach was to comment on the answer and had given me a suitable chance to improve it.

[This comment](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/are-the-moderators-biased)  from the moderator who handled the answer for another topic and see the difference in how both issues had been handled.

> @user3470 I handled you first flag. You commented in the flag that the answer is useless and wrong. Even though I agree that the answer is not really great and definitively lacks detail, I can't tell if it's wrong and there I can't tell if it is useless. The community has to decide that by voting. Therefore I declined your flag, but marked it as helpful since the answer definitively has quality issues. –  RoflcoptrException♦ Nov 9 '13 at 17:30

I present the matter to other community members

Comment: I'm genuinely curious - not trying to argue or anything, but you presented to the community, three people told you they agreed with the original decision, and so you take 'serious offense' from this and present it to 'other community members'? Until what, the 29th person to respond agrees with you?

Comment: It may happen that hundred may not agree with one but at the end that one may prove right. But then as expected you are taking the matter out of context, no offense meant. I am not here to argue or prove myself right but I believe that a person should stand up if injustice is done to him/her. We are not enemies but I just happen to disagree with you all and It doesnt matter if hundreds disagree with me :) because I stand on solid ground. All this doesnot matter me as I never intended to be here beyond few days and maybe I will forget about it all until you bring up the matter over beer :D

Comment: That's cool, but do consider that just maybe, if 100 people are disagreeing with you, just maybe - maybe, there might be a flaw in your working.  it *could* be the other way around as well, but Occam's Razor and all that.  Saying that, if we're in the same city at any point, I'll totally buy you a beer :)

Comment: [For beer requests](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/meet-other-travel-se-members)

Comment: In the end I will say crowd never makes history one person does. One of my favourite line (if I may) Everyone saw apples falling but it was newton who realised there significance and we got law of gravity

Comment: @MarkMayo On the other hand, it's not the first person complaining about heavy-handed moderation on this site (as opposed, say, to letting things run their course ‘organically’ through voting) and that does not seem to have an effect either.

Comment: @Annoyed sure, but by definition letting things run their course lets people in the community choose to flag something as low quality or spam or whatever the case may be, and the moderators then choose to agree/disagree.  You're never going to have 100% of the community happy with the moderators, or with the community for that matter.

Comment: @MarkMayo Since I wrote “run their course ‘organically’ *through voting*”, it's obviously not the definition I had in mind. I don't think short answers or duplicate question need moderator action and I do think it's easier to accept a closed question after one day of voting and five or more votes than after a flag and moderator action.

Comment: Fair enough. But while you don't think short answers need mod attention, it's set up as part of the system to allow it because Stackexchange thinks it's something the system needs, I guess.  Maybe enough people don't care about short answers that they originally saw too much low-grade stuff around, so decided this was a better solution? I'm only guessing here,.

Comment: @MarkMayo Short and low quality are two totally different things.

Comment: @kleineg different, yes, but they seem to correlate together well quite often here. Thus the mod message that Ankur posted above - for low quality ones, includes the mention of short.

Comment: @MarkMayo low quality or short, our first step is to comment on that answer so that community member is given a chance to *improve* their answer. We all are here to learn and giving a member a chance to improve is a great learning experience.

Comment: Short answers (one line) maybe sometimes more appropriate than big paragraphs, please donot forget that attention span of readers is not very long, many people searching for answers would prefer short to the point answers rather than *essay type* long answers which do not add any further value. Having said that we can always include explanation **if** explantion adds value to it and doesnot result in confusion to the reader. (Pratically *offline* I use short answers, I see more impact - its not rule it depends on lots of factors - not possible to list)

Comment: My experience here on SE is that low quality answers are **not** deleted *always* rather they are left as it is with downvotes as it reflects the *wrong answer* and that **also** is a great way of knowing of what **not to do**. Deleting an answer IMHO should be last resort. Specifically coming to the matter at hand I still stand firm, that, answer I gave was the most obvious and guessing as to which fuels goes in the car is **very dangerous**.

Answer (score 1):

It was deleted by a moderator because it's a low quality answer. A standard guidance is:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

Comment: Where is that quote from? It would be good to have the source so I can link people to it.

Comment: @starsplusplus it's a template tag/comment mods can add to a question or answer.  For example, [this question has it added to remind people](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19469/how-can-i-best-calculate-a-salary-when-the-job-title-they-are-offering-me-doesn)